# QUERY to return numbers from range in rows of 5

Tags: google-sheets

My data is a sorted list of numbers with multiple duplicates. I'd like to use `QUERY` to return them in groups of 5 -- so that if, for example, the number `7` had **8** instances, there would be **8** rows of the number `7`, followed by **2** blank rows (8 + 2 = 10, a multiple of 5).

Please reference the tab named **QUERY grouped by 5s** in the following sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L-XuT-H1pzl36OGGw5pPPLpkzX3kDrOxL2V7YIUr3hI/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried many different methods to no avail. I'd like to avoid Apps Script, if at all possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been racking my head against the wall for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L-XuT-H1pzl36OGGw5pPPLpkzX3kDrOxL2V7YIUr3hI/edit#gid=212069267). please test it out.

`=LAMBDA(ax,INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(ax,""))))(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",1,MAP(UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX(A2:A&""&B2:B&""&C2:C&"|"),A2:A<>"")),BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:C,A2:A<>"")),LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,COUNTIF(INDEX(A:A&B:B&C:C),JOIN("",ax))))),LAMBDA(ax,bx,IF(ax="",,{REPT(ax,bx)&REPT(" "&""&"|",CEILING(bx,10)-bx)})))),"|")))`

-

[image]

Comment: There's no easy way to say this: I made a mistake in my examples. Your solution does match the (albeit erroneous) pattern specified, and for that, you are amazing. I'm not familiar with the formulas you used, so I'm uncertain how difficult it is to modify and would struggle to modify it on my own.

I've updated the examples to reflect, correctly, the intent. I apologize for leading you astray.

Comment: updated the formula in your sheet. I only had to change the CEILING() value from 10 to 5.

Comment: that's so awesome. I really appreciate your help. There's no way I would have figured that out on my own.

Comment: UPDATE: Tried to use it with my actual data, and it's not functioning the same. I believe it may have something to do with the fact that some of my data has line breaks [entries with "CHAR(10)" in them] and your formula uses the pipe character: |

I've ran into issues in the past where the pipes and linebreaks were parsed similarly. Any thoughts?